# Named Query to SELECT rows with MAX(column name), DISTINCT by another column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a case similar to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql), I wrote an identical query which works, but when I try to write it as a jpql named query, I'm getting an error.

My query:

```
@NamedQuery(
            name = "findRankingsBetween",
            query = "SELECT rt FROM Rankingtable rt " +
                        "INNER JOIN " +
                            "(SELECT teamId, MAX(lastupdate) as MaxDateTime " +
                            "FROM Rankingtable " +
                            "GROUP BY teamId) grouped " +
                        "ON rt.teamId = grouped.teamId " +
                        "AND rt.lastupdate = grouped.MaxDateTime " +
                    "WHERE rt.lastupdate BETWEEN :from AND :to"
            )
```

Error:

```
Error in named query: findRankingsBetween: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 79
```

How to write the query properly in jpql?

Comment: check the query generated in your console and try running that query to your database gui

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524922/jpql-selecting-record-with-max-value), a subquery in JPQL can only occur in select and where clauses.
[Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries).

An equivalent query in JPQL is:

```
"SELECT rt FROM Rankingtable rt " +
"WHERE rt.lastupdate = (SELECT MAX(r2.lastupdate) " +
                       "FROM Rankingtable r2 " +
                       "WHERE r2.teamid = rt.teamid) " +
"AND rt.lastupdate BETWEEN :from AND :to"
```